# Opencart Where UPC = value

Tags: opencart

Как в Opencart добавить запрос `WHERE upc = 'value'` при условии того что в URL строке есть запрос &upc=value?

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день, в контролере проверьте наличие GET параметра upc,

```
if (isset($this->request->get['upc'])) {
   $upc= $this->request->get['upc'];
} else {
   $upc= '';
}
```

если Это контролер категории то добавьте upc в filter_data

```
$filter_data = array(
  'filter_category_id' => $category_id,
  'filter_filter'      => $filter,
  'sort'               => $sort,
  'upc'              => $upc,
  ....
```

);

передайте в модель и там уже в нужной функции допишите WHERE upc = 'value'.

```
if (!empty($data['upc'])) {
   ###дописываете запрос или что нужно там
}
```